# 404 in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 404

Is there a way to create a generic 404 page for an entire tenant ? Such that when a user hits anything that doesn't exist under https://.sharepoint.com/ it will throw this error page. On-prem you could have HTTP listeners and in SharePoint online I know you can do it at the Page Library level. How is this achieved at the Site Collection and Tenant levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that you have "Pages" library on your SharePoint site web. If not:

- Go to Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Site
  collection features -> active SharePoint Server Publishing
  Infrastructure
- Go to Site Settings -> Site Action -> Manage Site features -> activate
  SharePoint Server Publishing

In this library you should have "PageNotFoundError.aspx". If this page does not exist, create this page.

- New document -> Error Page

[image]

Please check 'vti_filenotfoundpage' parameter in 'Site Options'.

- Open your site in SharePoint Designer 2013
- Select the Site Object in the left tree-panel. Click 'Site Options'
  in the ribbon.
- Check 'vti_filenotfoundpage' parameter. If it does not exist, add this parameter.

[image]